# Merge Resulted Column From Pandas Dataframe Based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {
    "names": ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo', 'foxtrot', 'golf'],
    "Debit": [0, 5000, 0, 5000, 3000, 0, 700],
    "Credit": [1000, 0, 2000, 0, 0, 8000, 0],
} )
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame( {
    "names": ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo', 'foxtrot'],
    "db_head": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    "cr_head": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
} )
```

The output I want is:

```
     names  Debit  Credit   head
0    alpha      0    1000      2
1    bravo   5000       0      1
2  charlie      0    2000      2
3    delta   5000       0      1
4     echo   3000       0      1
5  foxtrot      0    8000      2
```

I tried to merge but did not understand how to get the value from two of the last columns based on the current df's column values

if merging without condition

```
print(df1.merge(df2, how="inner", on="names"))
```

by simply merging both of the dataframes resulted like this

```
     names  Debit  Credit  db_head  cr_head
0    alpha      0    1000        1        2
1    bravo   5000       0        1        2
2  charlie      0    2000        1        2
3    delta   5000       0        1        2
4     echo   3000       0        1        2
5  foxtrot      0    8000        1        2
```

tried these two methods but both of methods are giving error

```
df1['acchead'] = [df2[df2['names'] == x].db_head.item() if y > 0 else df2[df2['names'] == x].cr_head.item() for x, y in [df1['names'], df1['Debit']]]

df1['acchead'] = [df2[df2['names'] == x].db_head.item() if df1.Debit.item() > 0 else df2[df2['names'] == x].cr_head.item() for x in [df1['names']]]
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), then post-process the output with [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Serie.where.html):

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on='names', how='inner')

out['head'] = out.pop('db_head').where(out['Debit'].ne(0), out.pop('cr_head'))
```

Output:

```
     names  Debit  Credit  head
0    alpha      0    1000     2
1    bravo   5000       0     1
2  charlie      0    2000     2
3    delta   5000       0     1
4     echo   3000       0     1
5  foxtrot      0    8000     2
```

Other approach with a reshaping before the merge:

```
(df1.assign(variable=np.where(df1['Debit'].ne(0), 'db_head', 'cr_head'))
    .merge(df2.melt('names', value_name='head'), on=['names', 'variable'])
    #.drop(columns='variable')
)
```

Output:

```
     names  Debit  Credit variable  head
0    alpha      0    1000  cr_head     2
1    bravo   5000       0  db_head     1
2  charlie      0    2000  cr_head     2
3    delta   5000       0  db_head     1
4     echo   3000       0  db_head     1
5  foxtrot      0    8000  cr_head     2
```

Comment: In case of the dataframes has large number of rows which i am already getting from mysql, are you sure it will not make the procedure a little slower as getting records from mysql is already taking some time so i want the fastest method if the fethced rows in dataframe are around 90k

Comment: I expect it to be fast. It should be independent of the number of rows. It only depends on the number of columns.

Comment: Both of the approaches are working, I wish it will be helpful for people in future... (y) Thanks